# Writing OpenELEC Image on top of NOOBS

Tags: sd-card, openelec

I've ordered a Raspeberry Pi 2, and its sd card came with NOOBS installed. I took no consideration about it and just wrote OpenElec image into it.

I did,

```
dd bs=4M if=OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-5.0.5.img of=/dev/sdb
```

I just wonder if I should have formatted it before writing the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wonder if I should have formatted it before writing the image.

No, there is no point in formatting the card before writing an image to it with `dd`.  The image contains formatted partitions, and `dd` overwrites the card block by block, so any format data that was placed there would just be erased anyway.

Answer (score 0):

OpenELEC does not work on Raspeberry Pi2 http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ "52beec8af6f61f05d484dba4e4b594eef2b7f4b8
Pi Version supported: Pi 1 only"

Comment: http://openelec.tv/get-openelec

Answer (score 0):

You only need to format the sd card if it doesnt have a FAT (file allocation table)

Comment: ok, but i wonder if because NOOBS was installed I should have format it, before writing the image

Comment: if your install wasn't successful, then i'd suggest that you format your sd card (FAT 32) and then burn the img to the sd card.

Comment: my install was "successful". it works. however, my question is about if there is any risk on doing that! maybe it seems to work fine until a year because something.

Comment: If it works go with it.  Formating your sd card allows your pi to know how and where to read and write to the card.  If it works you did it right!  Hope this helps

Comment: No. You don't need to format your card before using `dd`.